# vue.js get id from select to axios post and display another select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

Probably this is a very stupid question, i'm new in vue.js and javascript, so please forgive me if the question is not properly explained or the answer is simple... I have a problem
I wanted to get the **id** from one select, and put that id into the other api and display the models in the next select, the listings work beautifully as I do the rigid.
But I don't know how to pass/paste the id into the async mounted axios function "api/sd/model/get", id)"

This is my template

```html
   
  <main class="home-page">
   
       <select v-model="selectedMark">
        <option v-for="model in items" :key="model.id">{{ model.name.value  }}</option>
      </select><br><br>

        <select v-model="selectedModel">
        <option v-for="make in info" :key="make.id" >{{ make.name.value }}</option>
      </select><br><br>

      
        <button type="submit" class="conectButton">Połącz</button>
      <div class="titleCarMain"><p class="titleCar">{{selectedMark}}</p><p class="titleComponent">{{selectedModel}}</p></div>
    
     
  
     </main>
```

And this is script

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
      return {
      
      
      info: null,
      items: [],
      selectedMark: null,
      selectedModel: null,

      };
  },
  
  async mounted() {
   axios
     .get("http://local/api/sd/make/get")
     .then(response => { this.items = response.data.data.items });
    

    const id = { id: this.selectedMark }  //dont work 
     
    await axios
     .post("http://local/api/sd/model/get", id) //dont work 
     .then(response => { this.info = response.data.data.items });

   },
   
  
};
```

Any good soul who can help this newbie? (if can explain the why of the solution as well, for understand, will be amazing!!)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work right now, because when the component is mounted **selectedMark** is equal to null as you define it at the beginning. If you want to fetch data from "http://local/api/sd/model/ge" endpoint in the *mounted* hook you have to establish **selectedMark** somehow - e.g. the id of the first item.

```
async mounted() {
  this.items = await axios
   .get("http://local/api/sd/make/get")
   .then(response => response.data.data.items);
  
  if (this.items.length) {
    this.selectedMark = this.items[0].id
    const id = { id: this.selectedMark }
    await axios
      .post("http://local/api/sd/model/get", id)
      .then(response => { this.info = response.data.data.items });
    this.selectedModel = this.info.length ? this.info[0].id : null;
  }
},
```

But if you want to fetch new data every time you select a different item you have to create a function that will be triggered on the change event.

```
<select v-model="selectedMark" @change="onchange">
    <option v-for="model in items" :key="model.id" :value="model.id">
      {{ model.name.value  }}
    </option>
</select>

async onchange() {
  this.info = await axios
    .post("http://local/api/sd/model/get", { id: this.selectedMark })
    .then(response => { response.data.data.items });
  this.selectedModel = this.info.length ? this.info[0].id : null;
}
```

Remember to add :value attribute to option tags

Working [example](https://codepen.io/tymoteuszlao/pen/ZExWvaK) **BUT** with the use of JSON placeholder FREE REST API (just to be able to show you how it works)

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response but first method almost works but it always selects the first id in the list.

Comment: And second Nothing downloads on the second list.

Comment: @Okatawo It selects the first Id because of this line: this.selectedMark = this.items[0].id - this was only an example you can choose different approach. But maybe you can explain exactly what you are trying to achieve (how this component should work), so we could help a little more?

Comment: Thank you for your involvement, from the first url Api, I retrieve a list of car brands,(audi, bmw, skoda...) and then from the second api I download the list of car brands(a4, a6), after selecting the models and brands want to go to the next window. I wanted the user to be able to select all this dynamically.

Comment: So the first API call works correctly, but the second is not, right? Did you check if the _selectedMark_ has some value assigned or if the second API call is correct? (By using postman or some static data)

Comment: I checked, with postman (it works) and typed the id on the rail in body axios.... Both work well,  When I pass on the id eg selectedMark: "104", then it works, but I wanted it to take ID from the first select and pass in the body to second axios. And it's just not working.

Comment: .post("http://local/api/sd/model/get", { id: 87 }) -this works, but this is hardcode not dynamic

Comment: @Okatawo [Here](https://codepen.io/tymoteuszlao/pen/ZExWvaK) is an example I made. I use JSONPlaceholder free API to make it work, so it is not exactly the same but overall it should work very similarly. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Sorry it's only now, I checked it didn't want to work but there was an error 400. I managed to fix it by replacing GET in your code with POST... 
Thank you so much :) 
And I see that the world small, Greetings from Poland :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@change` event and use `Methods` hook as below.

```
<template>
  <main class="home-page">   
    <select v-model="selectedMark" @change="getInfo(selectedMark)">
        <option v-for="model in items" :key="model.id">{{ model.name.value  }}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select v-model="selectedModel">
        <option v-for="make in info" :key="make.id" >{{ make.name.value }}</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="conectButton">Połącz</button>
    <div class="titleCarMain"><p class="titleCar">{{selectedMark}}</p><p class="titleComponent">{{selectedModel}}</p></div>
 </main>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
      return {
        info: null,
        items: [],
        selectedMark: null,
        selectedModel: null,
      };
  },
  created() {
    this.getItems()
  },
  methods: {
    getItems() {
        axios
        .get("http://local/api/sd/make/get")
        .then(response => { this.items = response.data.data.items });
    },
    getInfo(selectedMark) {
        await axios
        .post("http://local/api/sd/model/get", selectedMark) //dont work 
        .then(response => { this.info = response.data.data.items });
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but It still does not transmit anything to the second select, the console also does not print any error in total

Comment: @Okatawo I have updated the answer. Can you check now?